# CrossFilter - How can I use the "key" data into reduce methods?

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I'd like to use the "key" value from the crossfilter groups inside reduce methods. These ares the methods: `

```
function reduceAdd_Active(p, v) {
++p.count
p.sum += v.Price
p.avg = p.sum / p.count;
p.price += KEY * p.avg * p.count;
return p;
};

function reduceRemove_Active(p, v) {
--p.count
p.sum -= v.Price
p.avg = p.sum / p.count;
p.price -= KEY * p.avg * p.count;
return p;
};

function reduceInit_Active() {
return { count: 0, price: 0, avg: 0, sum:0 };
```

¿How can be made?

Comment: What are you asking? Please clarify this question.

Comment: Where,  in the code, I've written "KEY" is what I need to know. The way to access to the "key" data of the groups.

Comment: How in the world do you expect us to know what "KEY" is? It does not exist in the scope of the functions you've given us.

Comment: Where,  in the code, I've written "KEY" is what I need to know. The way to access to the "key" data of the groups. For instante, the first objet of the group is: Object { key:20, value { avg:0.05 , count:9, price: ¿?, sum:0.47} }  I need to calculate "value.price" using "key" (20 in this example).

Comment: I don't understand the down votes here. It's pretty obvious what is being asked if you know anything about Crossfilter groupings. The question is titled and tagged as Crossfilter, so...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is that it is not accessible in the reduce functions. You would have to re-derive the key from the data record that is passed in (`v`).

Comment: That's what I did. Thanks.